# Embeding/Loading Youtube video into Lightbox 2

Tags: html, youtube

Are you familiar with lokesh dhakar Lightbox 2? 
I am trying to display a gallery of videos using this version of lightbox. But for some reason when i put the youtube video embed code it doesnt display in the light box. Just shows an empty light box.

```
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/k6mFF3VmVAs?rel=0" data-lightbox="Video" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```

is the code that I am using. But it doesnt seem to work for me.

Is this a javascript problem or CSS?

NOTE : I am coding from scratch not using drupal or wordpress etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think Lightbox 2 is only for images popup not embeded videos. You can try custom JS for getting your designed effect.